# How to get an old kernel version that is not anymore in official webpage

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel, brightness

Im really frustrated with the new kernel patches, Im gonna explain why

### My laptop : Lenovo Z500

Intel core i7 3gen / Intel HD Graphics 4000
8GB RAM - DDR3 / NVIDIA Geforce 740M

The problem is the brightness of the integrated Intel card.
I know that there are 'solutions', because I did all of them.
Creating .conf files, editing /etc/default/grub, blacklisting, things that half-worked in the process.

None of them work as I want to.
The bug is that the brightness as default is not at maximum, and you can't control the brightness, and If you force it(meanwhile grub loads) the brightness go to 0, and then it locks...

So what I want is the same performance as I had in the kernel 3.13.0-24-generic that is in a burned CD with ubuntu 14.04(april of 2014), that kernel version... rocks! .
It was completely compactible with my laptop everything worked fine.

And I will detail you the features that means "fine"

- When I press the brightness keys It smoothly change the brightness(the bugged kernel version 3.13.92-generic do this but with low fps)
- It can reach the maximum brightness of the screen
- When the laptop is inactive, the brightness decreases really smooth
  until certain point, then the screen turns off.

That features are in windows too and I really liked that linux offers me the same experience.

Allright so the thing is that I want that kernel back, and I don't know how to "extract" the package from that old CD, because is not anymore on the official 'kernel.org'.
Ubuntu official repositories offers me updated kernels that spoil everything(that's why I'm not using 16.04) because Intel released an 'update' to his driver and the bug is even on Windows, the same bug of brightness, the solution in windows was to change some value to ffff in regedit, but in linux I tried everything(I saw like 22 different posts and none of them work properly), as I said in the begining of this post.

At certain point I though that was a Ubuntu problem so I tried Fedora, LinuxMint, Elementary, Debian even ArchLinux*, trying to successfull install NVIDIA and Intel Graphics, my dream is to have a full working laptop with gnu/linux

So...

### How can I get the kernel 3.13.0-24 back?

### How can I skip kernel updates?

### Can I get working updated versions of linux distros with that old kernel?

*I successfully installed bumblebee with nvidia in arch but I cant get working it on debian distros, not sure why I followed several tutorials and oficial distros how-tos that led me to finally return to ubuntu because I hate AUR and the fact that arch is not on the list for most supported software.

**Sorry for my english, I'm still learning, not sure if the title is correct please edit it if its possible

Comment: Fixed, just add a parameter in grub.cfg
after "quiet splash" add "quiet splash acpi_backlight=video"

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would like to know why you hate AUR. It is important for an open source community to allow for user-create packages that can be installed as easily as official packages. It's usually a beginners mistake to mess up user accounts and not be able to run *yaourt* from root.

Now, if you want a specific kernel version, all you need to do is get it from here - http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.13-trusty/. You'll have files like this:

`linux-headers-xxxxxx-generic-xxxxxx_amd64.deb`

`linux-headers-xxxxxx_all.deb`

`linux-image-xxxxxx-generic-xxxxxx_amd64.deb`

Move all of them to a folder. Go to that folder and then run:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

That should solve your problem.

To avoid/skip kernel updates, you can follow this: http://hollysydney.com/article/prevent-ubuntu-upgrading-kernel.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you very much It's highly appreciated 
the reason I hate AUR is dpkg I read and read the wiki like 13 times and I don't get how that thing works, I don't want to use yaourt it's against the arch philosopy. Another thing is that every program I try to find in AUR, is named in the webpage but when download is over, errors like 404 not found , constantly appears. Even with programs like chrome(I hate chromium because is blue) I can't install because of aur, I read a lot in arch and ubuntu must follow that initiative, but the fact here is that
In ubuntu I can install things easy in arch no

Comment: @RenatoMonroy, Ah yeah that makes sense. It'll take some time getting used to the errors and getting past them. But yes, in that sense, Ubuntu is definitely more user-friendly! Arch is usually recommended either when (1) you want a highly customised linux distro and don't want to go through the ordeal of LFS (2) when you really want to understand how linux functions! But yes, I see your point :)